# Is is possible to validate propTypes on component usage with eslint

Tags: reactjs, eslint, react-proptypes

Is it possible to validate `propTypes` during linting/building in places where the component is used? E.g. when I have a typo:

```
<MovieList moviesx={movies} />
```

or I have added or renamed prop on the component and I want to get info about places that do not have correct prop types? But I'm not interested in runtime console warning.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [flow](https://flow.org/)

This is exactly the purpose of @flow.